# Using has_many through associations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a few simple relations in my Rails 4 application. I have three models: **user**, **list**, **word**.

This is for a simple 'list' application, where each user has_many words through lists.

I currently have the following associations...

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :words through :lists
end
```

List model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :words
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Word model:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
end
```

I'm not sure how to create the relationships through the console. For example...

```
>   user = User.create(name: "Kyle")
>   list = List.create(name: "List One")
>   word = Word.create(word: "StackOverflow")
>
>   list.push(word)     # add word to list
>   user.push(list)     # add list to user
```

Can someone please give an example on how to correctly create these associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :words, through: :lists
end
```

#### List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :words
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Word model

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

#### creating objects:

```
> user = User.create(name: "Kyle")
> list = List.create(name: "List One")
> word = Word.create(word: "StackOverflow")

# Add word to a list
> list.words << word
> list.words.create(word: "LinkedIn") # Add a newly created word directly
> list.words << Word.find(params[:word_id]) # Add an existing word after finding it by its id

# Associate a list to a user
> user.lists << list
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Using Rails 4.2 - This gives an error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `list_id`

Comment: Also, note the ` has_many :lists` I added in the `User` model.